# double quotation with tilda expansion and backslash

Tags: bash

Why is the following wrong?

```
$ cd "~/my data"
bash: cd: ~/my data: No such file or directory

$ cd ~"/my data"
bash: cd: ~/my data: No such file or directory

$ cd ~/"my data" # works
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That how bash [tilde expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html) works:

> If a word begins with an unquoted tilde character (‘~’), all of the
>   characters up to the first unquoted slash (or all characters, if there
>   is no unquoted slash) are considered a tilde-prefix.

---

Lets assume your home directory is `/home/user` and you're currently in it, the **first** example:

```
cd "~/my data"
```

This tries to `cd` into a directory with the path `/home/user/~/my data/`. Notice that `~` is a valid character in directory or file names.

---

The **second** example:

```
cd ~"/my data"
```

This does the same as the first. If your wonder, it's because the slash is quoted, as stated in the citation above.

---

The **third** example:

```
cd ~/"my data"
```

This does tilde expansion, because the slash is not quoted, and is therefore replaced by the contents of the `$HOME` environment variable. This changes to the directory `/home/user/my data/`.

Comment: thanks. In the first example, is it `./~/my data/` rather than `/home/user/~/my data/`?

Comment: @Tim Yes, from that directory you're in it's `./~/my data`. I wrote the absolute path in the answer.

Comment: "all of the characters up to the first unquoted slash" does not include the first unquoted slash, correct?

Comment: @Tim Correct, see the link in the question for tilde-prefixes.